# Any further documentation/tutorial/example of sendBroadcastAsUser?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

The only documentation on sendBroadcastAsUser says this:

> sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, String
>   receiverPermission)
>
> Version of sendBroadcast(Intent, String) that allows you to specify
>   the user the broadcast will be sent to.

But I've not been able to find any examples of how the user is specified, or how you would set up a listener to listen to such a broadcast.

Within the AOSP source I found this example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra(PhoneConstants.STATE_KEY,
        DefaultPhoneNotifier.convertCallState(state).toString());
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(incomingNumber)) {
    intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER, incomingNumber);
}
intent.putExtra(PhoneConstants.SUBSCRIPTION_KEY, subId);
mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, UserHandle.ALL,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

What does UserHandle.ALL mean as the specified user, if it literally means "all" then what is the point in using sendBroadcastAsUser() with ALL rather than just use the vanilla sendBroadcast()?

Would my app be able to listen to this particular system broadcast?

Comment: See [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers) very interesting information, what you need is [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers#Creating_and_Sending_the_Broadcast_Intent) I guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sendBroadcast()` - broadcasts the intent only to apps running in the current user

`sendBroadcastAsUser` allows to send broadcast to apps running in other apps. But this requires `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` permission which is not available to 3rd party apps. This is the reason, the api is not documented

> what is the point in using sendBroadcastAsUser() with ALL rather than
>   just use the vanilla sendBroadcast()?

sendBroadcastAsUser allows to send broadcast to a particular user , or in case UserHandle.ALL is used, to all the users.

> Would my app be able to listen to this particular system broadcast?

Yes, any broadcast sent to the user in which your app is running, will be able to listen to the broadcast as long as your app has permission to recieve that broadcast

Comment: Thank you, in the example broadcast posted with the question a listener therefore presumably need the READ_PHONE_STATE permission but is the INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission required only by the code doing the broadcasting, and not by the code doing the listening?

Comment: yes you are right, INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL is required only by the broadcasting code not by listening code

Comment: "sendBroadcastAsUser allows to send broadcast to apps running in other apps" you mean apps running in other users right?